# Что такое Ellipsis?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Экспериментировал с интерпретатором Python и наткнулся на следующее его интересное поведение:

```
>>> (...)
Ellipsis
>>> [...]
[Ellipsis]
>>> {...}
{Ellipsis}
>>> type((...))
<class 'ellipsis'>
>>> type([...])
<class 'list'>
>>> type({...})
<class 'set'>
>>> type(...)
<class 'ellipsis'>
```

Похожее поведение наблюдается при зацикливании списка:

```
>>> x.append(x)
>>> x[0]
[[...]]
```

Хотя это, по всей видимости, не совсем то.

Знает ли кто-нибудь, что это за загадочный Ellipsis и для чего он?

Comment: В показанном вами поведении ничего интересного нет, замените `...` на любой другой объект и будет то же самое (ну кроме того, что вместо класса ellipsis будет соответствующий класс объекта)

Comment: @andreymal, а гугл так не считает. Я там забил — и он утверждает, что троеточие — это специальная константа. https://pythonz.net/references/named/ellipsis/

Comment: Одно другому не противоречит, у этой константы никакого «интересного» поведения нет

Comment: @andreymal, вы переходили по ссылке? Там говорится, что у этой константы как раз таки есть специальное применение в синтаксисе срезов.

Comment: Ну да, `ellipsis` - это просто словесное название для многоточия `...` в питоне

Comment: @Глеб там нет никакого специального поведения, это просто numpy использует этот объект для каких-то своих личных нужд

Comment: @andreymal, у меня numpy не установлен, а ellipsis присутствует.

Comment: `type((...))` - это тоже самое, что `type(...)`, лишние скобки просто игнорируются. Тоже самое с `(...)` - это просто `...`

Comment: @Глеб и это никак не противоречит ранее упомянутым мной фактам

Comment: @andreymal `Numpy` то тут при чём, это родной объект питона )

Comment: @CrazyElf спрашивайте Глеба при чём, это он решил своей ссылкой на numpy сослаться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal А, теперь понял, о чём вы )

Comment: Ну а вообще в Python 2 многоточие было разрешено было только в синтаксисе срезов (и тогда его ещё можно было кое-как с натяжкой назвать «специальным»), а в Python 3 добавили литерал `...`, который работает в любом месте кода, и таким образом он перестал быть специальным

Comment: Правда, остаётся открытым вопрос, а зачем его вообще изначально добавили. Кажется, Ellipsis появился ещё в версии 1.4 или 1.5, но описания причины его добавления я почему-то нигде не нашёл

Comment: Блин, и даже обоснование добавления литерала в Python 3 найти не получается — вот простое [«Yup.»](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-April/000996.html) от Гвидо и всё

Comment: Судя по коммитам в репозитории, [slice и ellipsis добавлены одновременно](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e15d0dea071d37b44ac3ba55a5cc31af315e7ef4) с описанием [«used by extended slice notation»](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b193c9516592e5873c412a35d8df5ee5cdb16188), но вот *зачем* это было сделано, я так и не понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ellipsis` - это просто класс, описывающий многоточие `...` в Питоне. У многоточия есть некоторые возможности - оно выводится в некоторых случаях и оно может использоваться библиотеками Питона для удобного обозначения каких-то вещей. Но в целом в нём нет ничего загадочного, это просто объект, как и всё в Питоне, с неким поведением.

Answer (score 3):

@CrazyElf, @andreymal, по вашим наводкам поискал, еще продолжает использоваться как заглушки для нереализованных кусков кода

```
if app.debug:
    def count_visitor(): ...
```

отсюда https://realpython.com/python-ellipsis/

и еще там момент, не особо осознаваемый, - требование единообразия типа в кортежах.

Comment: Да, его можно использовать как более визуально красивый вариант инструкции `pass` )